# Load previous (last) scene used

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, scene

Im making a 2D game for android and I made over 200 levels/scenes.I also made a game over scene that opens when the players collides with an obscale.In the GameOver scene I added a retry button which I wanna make it so it opens the last level played.Im new in Unity and scripting.I've read other similar questions but none of them fixed my issue.Anyone has any idea that could help?

Im doing this because I don't wanna create over 200 game over scenes and edit each obscale in game.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Often this simplest solution is the best. All you have to do is make your game remember which scene you where in. This is how.

Create a [static class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3.aspx) that will work as a container. That is, it will keep which scene you are currently in and it will exist through the whole existence of the game.

```
public static class LevelManager
{
    private static string lastLevel;

    public static void setLastLevel(string level)
    {
        lastLevel = level;
    }

    public static string getLastLevel()
    {
        return lastLevel;
    }

    public static void changeToPreviousLvl()
    {
        Application.LoadLevel(lastLevel);
    }
}
```

So then you call this method every time you load a new scene, except when you load the game over scene. You can do this by putting this line of code on a script that repeats throughout every scene, perhaps a Player script.

```
void Awake()
{
   // Call the LevelManager and set the last level.
   LevelManager.setLastLevel(Application.loadedLevelName);
}
```

You can mix and match Javascript and C# scripts. I do recommend you start switching over to C# little by little.

When the GameOver happens and the player wants to restart you have to call `LevelManager.getLastLevel()` to grab the string name so you can use that to load the new scene.

Comment: Hey,I tried to do what you said and it gives me 3 errors :

1."LevelManager.cs(13,31): error CS0708: `LevelManager.getLastLevel()': cannot declare instance members in a static class",
2."LevelManager.cs(8,29): error CS0708: `LevelManager.setLastLevel(string)': cannot declare instance members in a static class",
3."LevelManager.cs(6,32): error CS0708: `LevelManager.lastLevel': cannot declare instance members in a static class"

Any idea how to fix this ? Ty.

Comment: I have updated the code. Try it now, I forgot to make all the functions and variables static.

Comment: I added the second script to my character (constant) moving script,and I created another C# script and pasted the first script you shared.Am I supposed to edit something in my GameOver scene or attach the first script somewhere or what,Im a little bit confused as Im not used to C# scripting.
Ty.

Comment: Don't attach `LevelManager` to anything just call its functions from your character using `LevelManager.setLastLevel(Application.loadedLevelName);`. **Does your GameOver scene still have the character?** If it doesn't you don't need to change anything there except for calling LevelManager and grabbing the sceneName if the user hits replay.

Comment: It kind of fixed my issue,ty man!

Comment: I just added a new function to `LevelManager.changeToPreviousLvl()` when called it loads the previous scene for you. Good luck on the game!